# why does r not exclude NAs with filters

Tags: r

In R I have the d data frame below and I get NAs in the result so X>5 includes the NAs. What is the reason for R not excluding the NAs?

```
d =data.frame(group=c("NA","NA","a","b"),x = c(NA,NA,9,5),y = c(1,2,3,4))
d[d$x>5,]
```

I know dplyr will exclude them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic rule as explained in Advanced-R:

> A missing value in the index always yields a missing value in the
>   output:
>
> ```
>  x <- c(2.1, 4.2, 3.3, 5.4)
>  x[c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, FALSE)]
>  ## [1] 2.1 4.2  NA
> ```

Its pretty easy to understand the logic in context of `data.frame` with set of examples. Theoretically, difficult to explain clearly. Have a look at following examples and look at rule described at end:

```
d[c(NA, NA, NA, NA), ]

#       group  x  y
# NA    <NA> NA NA
# NA.1  <NA> NA NA
# NA.2  <NA> NA NA
# NA.3  <NA> NA NA

d$x>5
#[1]    NA    NA  TRUE FALSE

d[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA), ]

#    group  x  y
# 1     NA NA  1
# NA  <NA> NA NA

#And Finally:

d[c(NA, NA, TRUE, FALSE), ]    # matches with d[d$x>5,]

#      group  x  y
# NA    <NA> NA NA
# NA.1  <NA> NA NA
# 3        a  9  3
```

Now, one can understand behavior of `TRUE/FALSE/NA` with row-index selection:

```
TRUE  -- Row is selected
FALSE -- Row is not selected
NA    -- Row is selected in indeterminate stage. Meaning all columns will have NA
```

**Sample Data:** (*As provided by OP*)

```
d =data.frame(group=c("NA","NA","a","b"),x = c(NA,NA,9,5),y = c(1,2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
> d[which(d$x>5),]
  group x y
3     a 9 3
```

If you do the test:

```
NA > 5
```

You get the output:

```
[1] NA
```

The same here:

```
> d[NA,]
     group  x  y
NA    <NA> NA NA
NA.1  <NA> NA NA
NA.2  <NA> NA NA
NA.3  <NA> NA NA
```